# changing kinect angle changes the body angles

Tags: c#, kinect

I have come across a problem and I don't have any clue how t fix it 
I am finding angle of  various joint of  body (let say  shoulder joint)
the problem is  setting kinect at different heights and at different angles 
changes the angle of joint  what should id do

I know when way is to fix the height kinect from floor and set the angles in my application  to one kinect angle but that is not good programming. If some one changes the kinect angle all if the joints angles will b  different what should I do??

Comment: What are you using the angle for? Why can't the angles differ? Technically when Kinect measures the angles, they will be relatively different when the sensor is at different heights/angles...

Comment: yes this is the  problem   when kinect  is se to different height/angles  my body angle changes i am using the angles to perform some exercise and  i am matching the angles returned  with the angles that i have stored in my app ...what should i do

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("Don't move the Kinect or it won't work anymore");` easy and effective

Comment: well that is not the answer i was looking for  it wont help my cause @Alex

Comment: That was a bit of a joke (but it's the most common approach when it comes to sensors and software: "don't juggle it") On a side note, moving the arm would also change the angle unless I'm missing something... What's your final goal ? In other words: what's your application supposed to do, once finished ?

Comment: i am trying to perform a exercise and it involves angles  and those angles have to match a certain range which is coded in my application but  different position of kinect returns different angles than expected

Comment: How about calculating the values based on the kinect angle? You can do that by using math.

Just to be sure : Kinect Angle in your question, do you mean the angle that the sensor is looking and you can change by code or the angle of the whole device?

Comment: kinectsensor elevation angle  when changes its axis changes which affects my joints angle....any help??

Answer (score 3):

This is why many games institute a "Calibration" phase during start-up of a level, etc... the software requiring calibration lets the user know not to change the angle after calibration by default.

Comment: any sort of link that i could use ?? any examples  please

Answer (score 1):

For "Calibration" you can check this page http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/One-example-of-a-Kinect-calibration-method

The main idea is storing the number of tracked joints for each angle and choosing the angle with maximum number of joints tracked.